# Dynamic vs Direct Octal Character Representation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ascii, octal

If I was to create a three digit octal character string the following way:

`x = "\\" + a + b + c`

Where `a` is either 0 or 1, and `b` and `c` are both a number from 0 to 7, why would `alert(x)` result in `\141` for example, and not `a` which is `alert("\141")`?

Second to this, how would you get the original *created* character code to result in its respective ASCII character?

Answer (score 1):

> why would alert(x) result in \141 for example, and not a which is alert("\141")?

Because inside a string literal, a `\\` and `\` are different things. The first creates an actual backslash in the string, whereas in your second example, the backslash introduces an octal escape sequence. It's the same reason `\\n` in a string literal is a backslash followed by the letter `n`, but `\n` is a newline.

Or somewhat more simply: Because you're doing nothing that tries to ***re***interpret what you've created as a string literal. It's already a string, and nothing tries to evaluate the characters inside it using the string *literal* rules a second time.

> how would you get the original created character code to result in its respective ASCII character

If I'm understanding the question correctly, two ways:

1. Strip off the `\\`, convert the remainder of the string to a number via `parseInt(..., 8)` (octal), and then use `String.fromCharCode`.
2. Use `eval`. But don't do this, do #1

---

Side note: Octal escape sequences aren't part of standard JavaScript, although in loose mode implementations [are *allowed*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.2), but not required, to support them. They're not allowed in strict mode at all.

Comment: My second suggestion was going to involve JSON.parse, but I wasn't sure if all browsers supported passing a string directly

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Doesn't matter, JSON doesn't support octal escapes. :-) (I thought of it too, but then remembered...) BTW, the JSON standard has dropped the requirement that the top level be an object or array, and I'm not sure any browser actually enforced it in `JSON.parse` (since people frequently parse fragments with it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Humor me here, although I know it's not allowed and all but I can seem to figure out how you'd be able to use `eval` in this situation? Just so that I know what *not* to do, what would be the `eval` syntax to avoid?

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio: `x = eval('"' + x + '"');` :-) But really, don't do that, it's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're escaping the backslash. Also I'm not sure if JavaScript supports octal encoding, I know it supports hex using `\u61` (equivalent hex for octal 141) but if you want to specify it dynamically like that, try using something like this:

```
// a, b, and c are octal digits

var octal = parseInt('' + a + b + c, 8);

var x = String.fromCharCode(octal);
```